# Form submit mailto

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-email

i have a little problem,
i have developing html, css, javascript application for iphone and i have a form that submitting mails like:

```
<form action="mailto:some email" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
name:
phone:
email:
comments:
</form>
```

and when i click send, iphone email application opening with all the details, but all the details converting to gibberish (all the text is in hebrew).
how can i manage the details remain in hebrew and not converting to gibberish in the iphone email app?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your webpages charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailto:` URIs in forms are [too unreliable to use on the WWW](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). Use an HTTP URL instead and send the email from your server (this will require some form of server-side programming, but the specifics will depend on your choice of programming language).

Comment: i dont really know how to do this..:(

Comment: Pick a programming language you can run on your server. Google for how to send email with it.

Answer (score -1):

Use a UTF-8 encoding type in your form declaration:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8"
```